# What is the best way to pass sensitive data while using a URL redirect?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, webserver, websphere-portal

I am looking at a web application that redirects a user to a different site based on a user selection.  Following is the scenario

1. The user logs in to a web portal (IBM WebSphere portal)
2. Then user makes a selection, the user is redirected to a JSP page on a different web portal (running WebSphere).  But right now no other data is passed to the JSP.

I would like to pass some sensitive data (the user id in this case) to the redirected page. I can do the following:

http://newsite.org?UserId=xxx

However I am uneasy about passing the data as a query string.  Would using https instead of http help? What are my options?

Comment: Are you able to control how the other website accepts data? Shouldn't you be able to see in what forms the other website can accept this data first? Depending on that you can make a more informed decision? You can even ask the user to re-enter their password on the new website if required.

Comment: If both sites are sharing a security realm, perhaps a Single-Sign On solution might do better? SSO between WebSphere (Portal or otherwise) installations using the same user registry is a fairly common thing and is well supported.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered a similar scenario and we encrypted the entire query string in request. We introduced a filter component which will then decrypt it and pass it on to the handler, on a very high level. You can use https or Post, but nothing is safe from intrusion untill you take a good care.